# Is there a browser which encrypts completely the user data?

Tags: web-browser, security, encryption, privacy

**Is there a browser that encrypts all user data?** I am thinking about computers used at work where several people like company administrators may have access and could potentially access these files.

Browsers like Google Chrome stores a lot of sensitive information. For example, on Windows, check folders like `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB` where you can find plain text data about visited websites.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent company access to personal data? If so, the answer is to not use company computers for anything personal.

Answer (score 0):

Data to the server is encrypted if HTTPS is being used.

It is assumed that its your machine, so local data is not encrypted.  If more than one person is using the PC with their own logins, Windows won't let another logged in user  access to it.

If you are concerned about it, you can use Private or Incognito mode, most browsers have this. The information is deleted when you close the browser.

You can also clear the storage, cache, logins etc, either manually or when you close the browser.

Comment: Clearing storage, cache, logins etc. frequently or use the incognito mode would be a workaround but maybe there is also a browser which supports encryption of such data.